# How to add a woothemes like notification bar?

Tags: html, css, notifications, wordpress-theming

I would like to add a fixed notification bar (like the yellow one [here](http://www.woothemes.com/)) on my website: http://balloonup.com.
I tried to put the followings just after the body:

```
<div id="notification-wrapper"
style="border-bottom: 1px solid #C69A00;
background-color: #FEF28F;top:0;
position: fixed;z-index: 99999;width: 100%;">
<em>Hello world!</em>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this yellow bar overlaps my header.

Any idea?

Comment: just move your header down. It overlaps because it's fixed. If it's to be there permanently, you'll need the header to move down however many pixels is being taken up by the notification bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In woothemes example they've just pushed down the first content box (#top) through `margin-top` with the height of the "notification bar" just like @rockinthesixstring wrote.